# Ideal size of image to be used for Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a collapsible toolbar there i want to set an image at background,I am using Image Loader library to improve the performance even though the image is appearing very slow.

here is my xml for toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
     android:id="@+id/ctl_scene_list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/iv_production_image"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:background="@drawable/ph_production_profile_pic"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:src="@color/silver_chalice_approx"
          app:layout_collapseMode="none" />

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="@color/black_40_alpha"
              app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
          </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I want to use single image for all type of resolutions , is it recommendable to use image based on resolution and check for resolution in code ,and what should be ideal size of image while uploading at server?

Comment: What's the image resolution? If it's too high, that might not be needed because it's being shown on a mobile phone, and that might increase the time taking to load it.

Comment: Resolution is 1440*1080 and size is 100 KB

Comment: This is a very high resolution, is there a way that you can downscale it?

Answer (score 2):

If the images are being loaded from a remote server, and the resolution is very high, that could affect performance in some devices.

Here's a suggestion: you upload the image to the server in a high resolution (this will be considered to be xxhdpi or xxxhdpi), and then you could have a server script which automatically creates scaled images for the remaining densities (mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi).

When you fetch the images from the server on your app, you just need to get the the device's screen density, and send it to the server as a GET/POST variable, so that it would respond with the image in the right resolution.

To get the device's screen density, you use this code:

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

These are the scaling ratios android uses:

0.75 - ldpi

1.0 - mdpi

1.5 - hdpi

2.0 - xhdpi

3.0 - xxhdpi

4.0 - xxxhdpi

**TL;DR:** Get the device's screen density, send it to the server as a GET/POST variable, and have the server respond with the right image for that density.